# search join query doesn't display another row if doesn't exist on other table

Tags: mysql

I have a table attempts and employee.

Attempts table

```
|ID | name | results   
| 1 | Paul | Passed        
| 2 | Paul | Passed   
| 3 | Paul | Failed
```

Employee

```
|ID | name | employee id
| 1 | Paul |   123
| 2 | John |   456
```

Expected result

```
name | passed |  Failed  | 
Paul |   2    |    1     |   
John |   0    |    0     |
```

here's my query;

```
Select employee.name, SUM( attempts.results =  "Passed" ) AS passed,
SUM( attempts.results = "Failed" ) AS failed from employee left join attempts on employee.name = attempts.name where employee.employee_id = 123 or employee.employee_id = 456
```

but my result is only one row which is Paul only . because on the table attempts. John is not there.

Comment: why should by the  `or employee_id is null` where in John has employee id = 456? should i change my joining table?

Comment: Oh I see. perhaps you need a `group by employee.name` at the end. my first post fixes a question you didn't ask! I'll remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

- Store the employee id in the attempts table and join on it, instead of name. It's faster and more unique. (what if there are two employees named Paul?)
- Your employee table has an id column and an employee id column. Not very clear. Consider renaming `employee id` to `employee code`
- Your attempt table is storing 'Passed' and 'Failed' in presumably a varchar column. Consider renaming the column to passed and use a boolean. Are there more than two results values? Can you 'Half Pass'? Can you 'Fail Spectacularly'?

I would write the query like this:

```
select e.name,
  count(case when a.results = 'Passed' then 1 else 0) as passed,
  count(case when a.results = 'Failed' then 1 else 0) as failed
from employee e
left outer join attempts a on e.name = a.name
group by e.name
```

Or if you take my suggestions on board:

```
select e.id, e.name,
  count(case when a.passed = 1 then 1 else 0) as passed,
  count(case when a.passed = 0 then 1 else 0) as failed
from employee e
left outer join attempts a on e.id = a.employee_id
-- where e.id in (...)
group by e.id, e.name
```

Comment: You are right that I should join it by employee id. thanks for this bro. I think  I know what some modifications I will do.

Comment: Using a `case` statement inside the `count()` allows you to throw all sorts of conditions in there, such as `passed with a score > 50` without a bunch of subqueries.